# plotting a factorial function in R

Tags: r, algorithms, arithmetic, numerics

I have problem trying to plot the following function in R:

[image: Click here to see The function]

The R code I'm using is:

```
N= seq(from=150, to=2000)

P= (factorial(60) / factorial(50))*(factorial(N-60) /factorial(N-150)) /(factorial(N) /factorial(N-100))

plot(N,P)
```

I appreciate your thoughts?

Comment: The factorial of 40 is `815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000`, can you see why that may be an issue?

Comment: You might be able to make some progress by working on the log scale using `lfactorial`.

Comment: Note that for $k$>$i$, $\frac{k!}{i!} = k \times k-1 \times~...~\times i+1 $

Comment: Strange, I have the impression I saw this exact question elsewhere. EDIT: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510834/how-to-plot-a-factorial-function-in-r

Comment: @Frédéric Although that observation may serve for small one-off calculations, it doesn't go far when using the computer in more general ways, such as for discovery, exploration, or even developing reusable software.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33596954/844723 for a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to write this by cancellation would be:

$$
P(D|N) = \frac{60\times 59\times\ldots\times 51\times(N-60)\times(N-61)\times\ldots\times(N-149)}{N\times(N-1)\times(N-99)}
$$

Note that the numerator and denominator both have 100 terms, and that for large $N$ they will still be huge. We can make this more numerically stable by computing the ratio of individual terms from the numerator and denominator and then computing the product of these ratios:

```
pdn <- function(N) {
  prod(sort(c(51:60, (N-149):(N-60))) / (N-99):N)
}
N <- seq(from=150, to=2000)
P <- sapply(N, pdn)
plot(N, P)
```

[image]

An alternate approach would be to compute the fraction in log scale:

```
pdn2 <- function(N) {
  exp(sum(log(c(51:60, (N-149):(N-60)))) - sum(log((N-99):N)))
}
N <- seq(from=150, to=2000)
P <- sapply(N, pdn2)
plot(N, P)
```

This yields pretty much the exact same plot.

Comment: Unfortunately variations of this will still overflow or underflow.  If you have to, you can alternate multiplication and division to try to avoid it.  But there are better and simpler ways... .

Comment: @whuber I included an approach based on logs at the end that should not underflow (I don't see how any of the code here could overflow).

Comment: Just change some of the constants in your first solution: you will quickly get overflows and be unable to complete the computations.  (*E.g.*, change `60` to `300`.)  Although summing logs works, why go to all that computational effort when the sums are already done for you with `lgamma` or `lfactorial`?  It's no problem on little problems like this, but if you tried to implement this approach with a big dataset it could bog down.

Answer (score 4):

Probability calculations can produce formulas involving astronomically large or small numbers, especially when factorials are involved.  Often there's extensive cancellation.  The problem is that intermediate values can greatly overflow or underflow the computer's capacity to represent real numbers.

**Use logarithms.**

`R` (and many other computing environments, even Excel!) offer a function that returns the logarithm of the Gamma function.  By definition,

$$n! = \Gamma(n+1).$$

Logarithms convert multiplication into addition and division into subtraction.  Thus, for instance, writing $\Lambda(x) = \log(\Gamma(x))$,

$$\log\left(\left(\frac{60!}{50!} \frac{(N-60)!}{(N-150)!}\right) / \frac{N!}{(N-100)!}\right) \\= \Lambda(61) - \Lambda(51) + \Lambda(N-60+1) - \Lambda(N-150+1) - (\Lambda(N+1) - \Lambda(N-100+1)).$$

These intermediate *logarithms* may be in the thousands (as in this case) or millions or even billions, but after all the addition and subtraction take place, the result may be the log of a reasonable number--perhaps a probability.  You may then exponentiate it.

The implementation in `R` or even in a spreadsheet looks just like the formula:

```
f <- function(n, i=60, j=50, k=150, l=100) {
  ifelse(n >= pmax(i,k,l,0),
         exp(lgamma(i+1) - lgamma(j+1) + lgamma(n-i+1) - lgamma(n-k+1) 
           - lgamma(n+1) + lgamma(n-l+1)),
         0)
}
```

Note the effort to avoid problems with values of `N` that are invalid and the use of `pmax` to provide a vectorized function.  Those are little computing tricks that can be implemented in any language, too.

In `R`, the vectorization allows the function to be plotted directly with the `curve` command:

```
 curve(f(x), xlim=c(0, 2000))
```

[image: Figure]

(Obviously this is not a probability distribution: the shape is approximately a triangle of base $1000$ and height $8\times 10^{-15}$, so its area is around $1/2 \times 1000 \times 8 \times 10^{-15} = 4\times 10^{-12}$, far less than $1$.)

Comment: Although `R` also offers a convenient `lfactorial` wrapper to return the logarithm of a factorial, the need to convert factorials into Gamma functions is ubiquitous, so I elected to use the more basic `lgamma` function in the illustration.